# Clear or empty a VLA

Tags: c++, class, null

I have a class member as a VLA referencing some other objects (i.e. contains pointers to other objects). I would like to empty it after I am done with the VLA contents.
Is setting its length to zero enough or do I need to set its individual elements to NULL before that or do I need to do both?

Comment: Setting elements to NULL suggests you are holding pointers, not objects. Could you show how you create and fill this array?

Comment: impossible to answer without more info.

Comment: Yes the array contains pointers to other objects.

Comment: C++ doesn't have VLAs. Could you clarify with a code sample please? (And if you _are_ using VLAs in C++, add a tag for your compiler please.)

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not have Variable Length Arrays in the sense indicated by use of the abbreviation **VLA** (as in C99).

Thus, while your question about what to do with a particular VLA in your code may possibly have meaning for some particular C++ *language extension*, it doesn't have meaning for standard C++.

Some source code, information about the C++ language extension, or whatever, in short, some *concrete description of the problem*, might have helped towards giving a more problem oriented answer, rather than just correcting some misunderstandings.

---

It is a reasonable guess that you would be well served by using a `std::vector` instead of whatever it is you're using.

However, it is also a reasonable guess that your question is really about VLAs in some C++ language extension, in which case advice to use `std::vector` could very well be ungood.

There is not information to decide on good advice.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: VLA are part of the C99 Standard, they are NOT part of C++ even if gcc allows them there.*

That being said, once an array is created you cannot *clear it*. The space for the array (be it a regular array or a VLA) is reserved until the end of the block (in a function) or until the end of the program (at namespace level).

If you wish for *resizable* arrays, you should use a *dynamic array*: it just turns out that the Standard Library provides `std::vector` for this usage.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), then do [`my_vector.clear();`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear).